# Morris.js Error: Graph container element not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, morris.js

[The error that I'm receiving.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87euU.png)

I'm trying to have a bar graph on my page but I keep getting this error on my chrome console. I think there is something conflicting with angularjs and jquery, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you show us an isolated example of this not working? perhaps use [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) ?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/VEVidrm9sn35kgJ23ZsH?p=preview

Here is the code, but I can't seem to get it to work on plunkr, maybe you can take a look at it? The main files are dashboard.html and scripts.js

Answer (score 0):

Iam Also getting same error . **Graph container element not found**

but what i done is . i forgot to place id name in element position 
some times it happen

```js
if($('#executive_data').length > 0)
  // Morris bar chart
  Morris.Bar({
   element: 'executive_data',
   data: [{
    y: '2006',
    a: 100,
    b: 90,
    c: 60
   }
```